# DB2 Error. Inserting to a table through select query

Tags: sql, db2

I am tryin to insert some data to a table usin a query that uses tables and subquery. The subquery is where the case clause is used, and a I get the error : ERROR [HY000] [IBM][Controlador ODBC de iSeries Access][DB2 UDB]SQL0420 - The CAST argument character is not valid.

I only get this error when I run the insert command. When I run the select command there are no errors. this is the query

```
insert into qlib.table 
select a.fieldkey, a.field2, ifnull(n.firstdate,0) as firstdate, ifnull(n.lastdate,0) as lastdate, n.totamount, n.timespan
from mainlib.tablea a
left join (select b.fieldkey, MIN(rtrim(b.year)||'-'||case when b.month<10 then '0'||b.month else rtrim(b.month)end) as firstdate, 
              MAX(rtrim(b.year)||'-'||case when b.month<10 then '0'||b.month else rtrim(b.month) end) as lastdate, sum(b.amount) as totamount, 
                  cast(count(b.year)/12 as char(2))||' Years '||cast(count(b.year)-(count(b.year)/12)*12 as char(2))||' Months' as  timespan
           from mainlib.tableb b
           group by b.fieldkey) n on n.fieldkey = a.fieldkey
```

Tableb contains monthly savings ok. The subquery returns the first year-month of  saving, the last year-month, the total amount, and the years and months span of saving monthly, under the assumption that every month there is a saving/deposit, for each fieldkey

Is there anything wrong with the cast clause of the subquery. Again I only get error when I am trying to insert to qlib.table using the select command.

Answer (score 0):

A few things might clean up your query:

`case when b.month<10 then '0'||b.month else rtrim(b.month)end`  can be replaced with
`VARCHAR_FORMAT(b.month,'00')`

`cast(count(b.year)/12 as char(2))||' Years '||cast(count(b.year)-(count(b.year)/12)*12 as char(2))||' Months'` rewritten as

`VARCHAR_FORMAT(count(b.year)/12,'99')||' Years '||VARCHAR_FORMAT(count(b.year)-(count(b.year)/12)*12,'99')||' Months'`